# creating new functions based on another function

Tags: python

I have a couple of functions defined like this (all parameters in a single array):

```
import numpy as np

def poly(x, params):
    val = 0.
    for i in range(len(params)):
        val += params[-1 - i]*(x**i)
    return val

a = 1.
b = 1.
c = 1.
params = [a, b, c]
```

Now I need to create the same function but without array as an argument of a function. I don't want to rewrite all my code, I need some new function for redefinition. The redefined function of my example should look like this:

```
def new_poly(x, a, b, c):
    #take all parameters and put them back in an array to make the rest of the code work
    params = [a, b, c]
    val = 0.
    for i in range(len(params)):
        val += params[-1 - i]*(x**i)
    return val
```

I will be grateful for any tips!

Comment: `def new_poly(x, *params)`?

Comment: There isn’t really a need for the `new_poly` function. You can just call the original function like this: `poly(x, [a, b, c])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and *ask a question* - "I will be grateful for any tips" does not qualify, because this is *not a discussion forum* and we are looking for a *specific* question (so that other people who have that question can find the post with a search engine, and get a direct answer).

Comment: The problem is I'm putting functions as arguments for scipy.optimize.curve_fit and the form `def poly(x, params)` is not valid. All parameters need to be called separately, like in new_poly. That's why I need to create a new functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args`:

```
def use_star_args(*args):
    params = [*args]
    print(params)

use_star_args(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `params = [*args]` is not necessary, it just makes a list with the same elements as the existing `args` tuple. If for some reason a list is desired, it would be better to be explicit: `list(args)`.

Comment: That's a good point.